# Regex remove special characters in filename except extension

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to remove any special character from a filename except the extension.

Im using the javascript `filename.replace(regex, '-');`

Original filename: `manuel fernandex – Index Prot.bla.otype 5 (pepito grillo).jpg`

Target filename: `manuel-fernandex-Index-Prot-bla-otype-5-pepito-grillo-.jpg`

With this one, i get any special characters in block, just what i need, but need to skip the extension of the filename:

`/[^\w\d]+/g`
Result: `manuel-fernandex-Index-Prot-bla-otype-5-pepito-grillo-jpg`

With this one, i remove any special character except the filename but also leaving all the dots in the filename:

`[^\d\w\_\-\.]+`
Result: `manuel-fernandex-Index-Prot.bla.otype-5-pepito-grillo.jpg`

Im very close but i cant find the final solution.

Comment: What is the problem with the last one? A file can certainly have dots in the name. In fact, in a file `myArchive.tar.gz` the extension *is* `tar.gz`. So the last regex seems fine. What do you want to do instead?

Comment: The problem is, the last one skips any dot in the string, not only the dot related to the extension. I know there is extensions with two dots, but this case is for media files and i don't have any scenario of files with that kind of extensions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may remove any chars other than word and dot chars with `[^\w.]` and any dot not followed with 1+ non-dot chars at the end of the string:

```
filename = filename.replace(/(?:\.(?![^.]+$)|[^\w.])+/g, "-");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YLGcwe/1)

**Details**

- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `\.(?![^.]+$)` - any dot not followed with 1+ non-dot chars at the end of the string
  - `|` - or
  - `[^\w.]` - any char other than a word char and a dot char
- `)+` - end of the group, repeat 1 or more times.

Another solution (*if extensions are always present*): split out the extension, run your simpler regex on the first chunk then join back:

```js
var filename = "manuel fernandex – Index Prot.bla.otype 5 (pepito grillo).jpg";
var ext = filename.substr(filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
var name = filename.substr(0, filename.lastIndexOf('.')); 
console.log(name.replace(/\W+/g, "-") + "." + ext);
```

Note your `/[^\w\d]+/g` and `/\W+/g` are equal as `\w` includes `\d`.

Or, if extensions are optional, split with the last dot, replace as in the previous solution, and join back:

```js
var filename = "manuel fernandex – Index Prot.bla.otype 5 (pepito grillo).jpg";
var parts = filename.split(/\.(?=[^.]*$)/);
parts[0] = parts[0].replace(/\W+/g, "-");
console.log(parts.join("."));
```

Comment: Im trying with a string with a underscore and is not detecting the underscore, but should be detected with the /w right?

Comment: @RicardoA `\W` does not match a *word* char. It does not match `_` as it is a word char. To replace underscores, too, use `.replace(/[\W_]+/g, "-")` with the 2nd and 3rd solutions. For the first one, use `/_|(?:\.(?![^.]+$)|[^\w.])+/g`

Comment: Hmm thanks!, i like the first one, looks more cleaner, all done in a single line.